# Modify XML tag using XSLT in Datapower based on condition

Tags: ibm-datapower

My XML:

```
<ns:document-service-requests xmlns:ns="com.metlife.us.ins.svc.docauto.docgen.request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" requestCount="1" requestPriority="7">
   <ns:document-service-requestor chargeCode="MGI" appName="MGIRAS" requestDescr="RAS DOC generation" requestor="MGIRAS" />`enter code here`
   <ns:document-service-request requestId="1117226deddeabed611e314caced611_INT2">
      <ns:document-templates> content     
      </ns:document-templates>
   </ns:document-service-request>
</ns:document-service-requests>
```

Need to check  if after '_' in requestId its INT2, so need to send entire xml after changing that INT2 to UAT

I have written XSLT but that is not working, could someone please help me with this on priority.

Comment: Anyone for help please

Comment: Tried with below xsl, but no luck 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="RequestID" select="/*[local-name()='document-service-requests']/*[local-name()='document-service-request']/@requestId" />
 <xsl:variable name="IdentifierVal" select="substring-after($RequestID,'_')" /> 
  </xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Anybody for much needed advice please ?